# variables outside of snapshot firebase Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

this may come across as simple but I've ran into this problem a lot with Angular and I need a little explanation. All I'm trying to do is get a variable value outside of the snapshot function. If I could do something like this

```
let testVariable : string;

var testCount = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userName + '/userName');

testCount.on('value', function (snapshot) {

testVariable = snapshot.val();


});

alert(testVariable); //comes out undefined
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code is running asynchronously. This means that javascript will make the call to firebase and immediately call the alert function, without waiting for any response. Your alert must either be placed in a callback or called after the variable has been set.

If you are using "this" you might have problems accessing this within the function. If so, change the function syntax to the arrows like this:

```
testCount.on('value', (snapshot) => {

     this.testVariable = snapshot.val();


});
```

Comment: In your function you run testCount. This function runs (gets an answer from firebase) then fires the callback function (the snapshot function). Callbacks are, very basically, when we tell js to wait for something else to happen before doing the next thing. Try moving the alert() function to just under testVariable = snapshot.val().

Comment: It would be more helpful if you put that code here. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Assuming navController.push is called after the variable has been set it should work. The only other thing that might be tripping you up is your function syntax. I'm updating my answer so you can see what I mean.